# Is Sqlite database browser is replacement of browser Cookies?

Tags: sqlite, cookies

Can we use sqlite database browser as a replacement of cookies which we written in browser?

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) is a *local UI program* to "create, design and edit database files compatible with SQLite". This of course has *nothing* to do with either a [web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser), or [HTTP cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) in a browser.

As such, the title makes no sense and this "SQLite Database Browser" *is not / cannot* be a replacement for "browser Cookies".

---

Previous answer that assumed the title contained "related" topics.

Local data persistence mechanisms and cookies are *not* direct replacements. As such, whether or not if "Sqlite can replace cookies" depends on *what* is being done/expected.

While "local storage" - in its many forms including localStorage, IndexedDB, Web SQL, and Flash - can store persistent data across page loads like cookies, persisted "local storage" and cookies are designed for fundamentally differently tasks.

One crucial difference is that cookies are *part* of the HTTP request structure

- Cookies are *sent* along with each request matching the cookie path
- Cookies can be directly set by the server

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the sqlite database browser, is it only to avoid complicate sql queries & to provide a GUI to end users?

Comment: @karthi Now I am confused :| What is this "Sqlite Database Browser" and how does it relate to "browser Cookies"? I read it to mean Web SQL (of which implementations use SQlite) - if you're talking about a UI tool for SQlite, then it has absolutely *nothing* to do with cookies and cannot replace cookies in any way.

Comment: @karthi Then no. It *cannot / does not* replace "browser Cookies".